# AppSettings for AzureFunction on .NET 8 (Isolated)

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-8.0, azure-functions-isolated

#### Context

I have an existing Linux Azure Function running on .Net 6 (In-process) v4. I have a lot of configuration coming from `appsettings.json`. Most of these configurations are objects with nested properties or arrays (nothing fancy, but common JSON). Some of these configurations are overridden by the Azure Environment Variable panel (former Configuration panel), especially for connectionStrings or some prod-related settings (expiry timer, etc), but most of the `appsettings.json` config is default settings to apply on each env.

### The problem

I am trying to update the Azure Function to .NET 8. According to the documentation, I have to migrate to the isolated worker model. This is a heavy breaking change and causing a lot of pain, but I can manage that. The real problem is that the `appsettings.json` config is not loaded anymore (as it used to) when running in Azure. Everything is fine when running locally. I wasted a lot of time trying to get it to load without success. Config is coming nicely from the Azure Environement Variable panel though.

### What I don't want to do

- I don't want to rely solely on the Azure Environment Variable panel as I don't want to replicate and maintain all the default configs in all environments. We have a plan to deploy configuration through bicep templates, but that has much more implications on the overall project infrastructure.
- I don't want to use the `local.json` as it is not able to deal with JSON objects or arrays. I would have to flatten all my configs and that would be a mess.

#### Code sample

I've reproduced the problem in a test project with a dummy setup and am experiencing the same behavior

`Program.cs`

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((appBuilder, services) =>
    {
        var configuration = appBuilder.Configuration;

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        services.Configure<DummyOption>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(DummyOption)));
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

        configBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, $"appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

`DummyOption`

```
public class DummyOption
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

`DummyFunction.cs`

```
    public class DummyFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DummyFunction> _logger;
        private readonly DummyOption _options;

        public DummyFunction(ILogger<DummyFunction> logger, IOptions<DummyOption> options)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        [Function("DummyConfig")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_options);
            return new OkObjectResult(json);
        }
    }
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "DummyOption": {
    "Foo": "Test"
  }
}
```

The function returns `{"Foo":"Test"}` when running locally but `{"Foo":null}` when running in Azure. The function returns `{"Foo":"yolo"}` if I add a `DummyOption__Foo` = `yolo` in the Azure Envrionement panel, but again I dont want to do that. This would be a pain to maintain and scale.

Also, I have added the following csproj code to deploy the `appsettings.json` file with the build, and confirmed the file exist next to the DLL in the Function App files.

```
      <Content Include="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
```

I even confirmed the file exists, and is accessible by adding some logs in `ConfigureAppConfiguration`.

Finally, by adding more logs in the `ConfigureService`, I can see the `appsettings.json` config is just not loaded in the configuration at all.

I am running out of options and would love some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It did worked for me by modifying the code like below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources):

**`Program.cs:`**

```
using FunctionApp132;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
               .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
               {
                   builder.SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                          .AddEnvironmentVariables();
               })
               .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
               {
                   var configuration = context.Configuration;

                   services.AddLogging();
                   services.Configure<DummyOption>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(DummyOption)));
               })
               .Build();

host.Run();
```

Added **`appsettings.Development.json`** in csproj:

**`Csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
      <None Update="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>
      </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Change `program.cs` and `csproj` according to mine then it will work for sure.

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I replicated your setup (which is fairly the same as mine) but was still unlucky. But since you apparently got it working, I investigated further. I redeployed my app to a windows Function and it just started to work. But I'm still unlucky on the Linux Function side. I'm sharing this result here for now and will investigate further during the day and get back to you.

Comment: No csproj is not same and not even program.cs is same, in csproj i have added this ```</None>
      <None Update="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>```

Comment: Mine will work for sure, as i have got exact result

Comment: I copied that exact `.csproj` and `Program.cs` and I still dont have it working on a Linux Function. Can you confirmed yours is also running on Linux?

Note: I'm deploying from VisualStudio for now using Zip deploy. (will do it through proper CI/CD after I got it working)

Comment: I can see the `appsettings.json` in the Function App Files, but it feels weird that it is not listed in alphabetical order (it is at the very bottom, after all the `.dll`. Can it be that it is stored differently because of the Linux OS and displayed as a flatten list of files from various locations?

It is listed in alphabetical order in the windows Function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get it working by adding this logic

```
if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() == false)
   builder.SetBasePath("/home/site/wwwroot");
```

#### So what is going on?

The application files (DLLs + `appsettings.json`) are deployed under `"/home/site/wwwroot"` BUT `context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` resolves to `"/azure-functions-host"` which contains the DLLs and `appsettings.json` of the Function Host (not the application itself). So `appsettings.json` was resolved to `{"IncludeScopes":false,"LogLevel":{"Default":"Warning"}}`

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` resolves to `"/tmp/functions\\standby\\wwwroot"` which isn't helpful.

This is fine on windows but apparently off for Linux. To be honest, I'm not a fan of the solution, but I can't think of anything else for now.